# Avoid record type selection with URL button

Tags: custom-button, urlhacking

I'm creating a url button to avoid the record type selection:

[image]

This is the code:
{!URLFOR($Action.Case.NewCase ,null ,[RecordType="01220000000Q3cy"])}

The problem is that i'm still getting the page record type selection.

Could you help me ?

Thanks in advantage for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following syntax:

```
{!URLFOR($Action.Case.NewCase, null, [p3='012............', save=1], true)}
```

This selects the record type to use (`p3=record-type-id`), and continues to the edit page (`save=1`).

Comment: Is there any documentation available for all of the URL parameters?

Comment: No, but I once compiled a list of useful ones: http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/forums/forumtopicprintpage/board-id/general_development/message-id/72819/print-single-message/true/page/1

Comment: It is not working,it still go to RecordType page selection but with the prepopulated value.Can we skip and directly go to the Case page with selected recordType?

Comment: @unidha currently it looks like you must avoid $Action.Case.NewCase and go straight to the hack: `URLFOR('/500/e', null, ['RecordType'='012000000000000'])`

Comment: @sfdcfox I can't get the Save=1 parameter to do anything. I can tell that the correct record type is being selected using the p3 value but I still land on the record type selection page. Any ideas why this would be? I have a new question open for my version of this issue.