# How to avoid Splash page prompting for record type selection?

Tags: record-type, new

I have 2 record types for a custom object created in salesforce. I noticed that it prompts everyone to select a record type when creating a record in this object.

I would like to avoid the splash page and select one of the record type as default whenever anyone creates a record. I referred some posts and found out that record type default settings can be changed under my Personal settings. But how do I ensure that any user does not go through this?

Comment: Best you can do is to create a custom button and add it on layout which sends user to specific pre-selected recordtype, refer [this](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54807/by-pass-recordtype-selection-when-creating-new-case) post.

Comment: Do you want them to be able to change to the other record type manually?

Comment: @Eric: No I do not want them to change it manually as there are many user profiles involved here.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want them to be able to select the other record type manually then you would edit the profiles to only have the one record type available.

Then you could use code / workflow rules to set the second record type based on conditions.

Otherwise, there is no way to skip the selection and still allow the user to change to another type. (Sans custom button, vf page, or some other override)

Comment: I have too many sales rep profiles to do this change (default record type). Is there a better way?